# I'm unable to position NSTextField correctly in NSBezierPath-drawn diagram

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield, nsbezierpath

I'm a beginner Cocoa programmer. I wish to position a Cocoa NSTextField (a subview of a custom view) programmatically next to a geometric diagram drawn on the custom view in a program to be developed with XCode 4.3.2 for OS X on Lion. To keep the example of my problem simple, let's say the diagram is to be a box enclosing the text field (additional to the bezel or border available with NSTextField, and further out; actually, my diagram is to be more complicated). I find that the text field and the box do not align as I expect (see example code below). Why?

I've made a simple non-Document-based project as a diagnostic example, in which I've dragged a custom view onto the application window, added the code below, and made the connection from the IBOutlet to the view:

AnAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AnAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSView *view;
    NSRect textFieldRect;
    NSTextField *textField;
    NSBezierPath *box;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

AnAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AnAppDelegate.h"

@implementation AnAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    textFieldRect = NSMakeRect(100, 100, 100, 20);
    textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];

    NSRect frame = [textField frame];
    NSLog(@"frame %f %f %f %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    NSRect bounds = [textField bounds];
    NSLog(@"bounds %f %f %f %f", bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);

    // Draw the text field
    [textField setStringValue:@"My text field"];
    [textField setBezeled:YES];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setEditable:YES];
    [textField setSelectable:YES];
    [view addSubview:textField];

    // Draw a box (rectangle) around the text field
    //NSRect boxRect = [textField frame];
    box = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
    //boxRect.origin.x += 10;
    //boxRect.origin.y += 10;
    //boxRect.size.width += 20;
    //boxRect.size.height += 20;
    [box appendBezierPathWithRect:[textField frame]]; // :boxRect];
    [box stroke];

}

@end
```

When this program is run, the box appears displaced to the left and below the text field, apparently by the height of the text field in each dimension. I'd expect it to appear 'underneath' the NSTextField subview, and to be hidden by it. (That's not sensible in a production program, of course.)

Now, to get closer to what I want, if one uncomments the commented-out lines of the source above (appending boxRect to the box path instead of the frame of the text field), then my box appears outset by 10 units from the text frame - but I expected that I should have had to add -10 units to the origin to do that, not +10 units.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into positioning, there are some larger issues that need to be resolved here.  You are misusing the Cocoa drawing system.  You can't (generally) just start drawing (as `[box stroke]` does) at any random spot in your application.  You need a graphics context set up.

For drawing to the screen, you put your code in a custom view's `-drawRect:` method.  The frameworks will make sure to set up an appropriate context before calling that method, and will tear down the context afterward.

I'm a little surprised your code is working at all, but as it is there is no well-defined graphics context, so we have no way to know what the relevant coordinate system is here; the drawing is basically going somewhere random.  Refactor your code in accordance with the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and you might get better results.

As an aside, you comment

`// Draw the text field`

**No!**  You are not *drawing* the text field; that is done by the frameworks for you during the next turn of the run loop when the various views' `-drawRect:`s are called.  You are *adding a view to the view hierarchy*.  This is not a pedantic difference: you can manipulate the view hierarchy at most(*) any time.  You can generally only draw in `-drawRect:`.

(*): Threading complicates matters, but this is probably not relevant if you are just beginning Cocoa.

Comment: Conrad, thank you. Although I've spent a day trying to understand why I had the offset, I have just noticed that my view is positioned at (20, 20) in the window. If I change that, the misalignment changes accordingly. But I will correct things overall as you suggest.

Comment: That will be irrelevant in `-drawRect:` since the coordinate systems will match. (You rarely use the window's coordinate system.) Fix the overall problems and the offset will disappear.